# Having trouble getting SageTeX working

Tags: installing, mac, sagetex

According to the [Make SageTeX known to TeX](http://sagemath.org/doc/installation/sagetex.html), the preferred way to let TeX know about SageTeX is to copy the `tex` folder found at `SAGE_ROOT/local/share/texmf/tex` (which in my OS X case is `/Applications/Sage-6.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/share/texmf/tex`) into the value returned by running `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` in the shell, which in my case is `/Users/chuck/Library/texmf`.

I've done that, and now `sagetex.sty` (and many other files) are found at `/Applications/Sage-6.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/sagetex`.

So I open the `example.tex` file (using TeXShop) also found in that `generic` folder and click the **Typeset** button. The PDF is generated and opened in TeXShop, but everywhere that should have the results of Sage operations instead has double question marks.

The console that appeared when I clicked **Typeset** has numerous errors, all of the same type:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `@sageinline0' on page 1 undefined on input line 40.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `@sageinline1' on page 1 undefined on input line 41.
```

Lines 40 and 41 look like this:

```
This is an example $2+2=\sage{2+2}$. If you raise the current year mod
$100$ (which equals $\sage{mod(\the\year, 100)}$) to the power of the
```

The PDF output at that point has the following text:

> This is an example 2 + 2 = ??. If you raise the current year mod 100 (which equals ??) to the power of the

Other simple tests of both Sage and TeX have proven successful. For example, launching the Sage app and selecting "Terminal Session>Sage" correctly outputs `4` with input `2+2`, and creating a very simple TeX document and running it using the `latex` command in the Terminal is also successful, so each of these seem to work separately without trouble.

What can I do to get them to work together?

Comment: In your post you said you compiled by pressing "Typeset". Using `sagetex` requires a 3fold [process](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/sagetex.html): latex the document, run Sage on the resulting sage file then run latex again; the ?? are consistent with 1 step. [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) can avoid this (done automatically) and installation hassles. If you have "Typeset" programmed in your IDE to go through the 3 step compilation process then you should consider asking your question at [AskSagemath](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/) if you can't get an answer here.

Comment: @DJP: Thanks, that's what I needed, and I should have read the page I linked to more closely. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXShop uses scripts it calls 'Engines' to typeset each document.  It is already set up to deal with Sage, but you need to activate the SageTeX engine.

In the Finder, navigate to `~/Library/TeXshop/Engines` and in that folder there will be an `Inactive` folder. Inside is the file `sage.engine`. Move this into the `Engines` folder, and restart TeXshop.

(You will also find some other documentation in the Sage folder, including a sample document.  It also recommends a different method of accessing Sage properly without copying it to your local `texmf` folder.)

Once you have restarted TeXShop, in the pulldown menu next to the Typeset button, the Sage engine will appear.  Select it and then compile your document.  Everything should now work.

You can add the line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = sage
```

to first line of your Sage documents and the sage engine will be chosen automatically.

Comment: I followed your instructions (after confirming them with the About SageTeX.pdf file found in that `Inactive` folder) and followed the instructions for creating the symbolic link, but TeXShop now complains that it can't find `sagetex.sty`. I also tried placing a copy of that file in the same folder as the `tex` file, but got the same error. I have had success by doing this process from the command line with the latex/sage/latex routine, and I'll try automating that, but would much prefer to get this working from TeXShop.

Comment: @Chuck I assume from your having accepted the answer that you have successfully got this working now?

Comment: It is possible that you will not see the Library folder immediately; see http://www.macworld.com/article/2057221/how-to-view-the-library-folder-in-mavericks.html .  Perhaps Shift-Command-G and then `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` is the easiest method on Lion; there appears to be a preference in Mavericks and on.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here are up-to-date links to SageTeX-related parts
of the SageMath documentation and to the SageTeX GitHub repository.

- [Using SageTeX](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html)
- [Make SageTeX known to TeX](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html#sec-sagetex-install)
- [SageTex repo on GitHub](https://github.com/dandrake/sagetex)